# How to get key by it's map property value

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to get `key1` by using `uniquevalue1` from the following object? If that's possible, how to get key by `othervalues` in 'an array'?

```js
{
  'key1': {
    anarray: ['othervalues '],
    value: 'uniquevalue1'
  },
  'key2': {
    value: 'uniquevalue2',
    anarray: ['othervalues ']
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `.find` a key-value pair:

```
 const [key] = Object.entries(input)
   .find(([, { value }]) => value === "uniquevalue1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example on how you can find the key by value.

```js
let arr = { 'key1': { anarray: [ 'othervalues ' ], value: 'uniquevalue1' }, 'key2': { value: 'uniquevalue2', anarray: [ 'othervalues ' ] }}

const findKeyByValue = (val) => {
    for(const key in arr) {
      if(arr[key].value.includes(val))
        return key;
    }
};

console.log(findKeyByValue('uniquevalue1'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Matches the value which is a string or inside an array

```js
function getKeyByValue(_json, searchValue, searchInArray=false) {

        for (const [key,val] of Object.entries(_json)) {

            const {anarray, value} = val;

            if (searchInArray && anarray.includes(searchValue)) {
                return key;
            } else if (searchValue === value) {
                 return key;
            }

        }

    }

    var data = {
        'key1': {
            anarray: ['othervalues'],
            value: 'uniquevalue1'
        },
        'key2': {
            value: 'uniquevalue2',
            anarray: ['othervalues']
        }
    };
    console.log(getKeyByValue(data, 'uniquevalue1'));
    console.log(getKeyByValue(data, 'othervalues', true));
```